# Ability to share capacity between activities in TFS

Tags: tfs, scrum

We are using TFS 15 with mixed teams and we like to use the activities for capacity planing a little better. But I can only set a capacity for a specific activity.

- Senior Developer Bill

  - 1.0 h for Development
  - 0.5 h for Testing
  - 0.5 h for Documentation
  - 2.0 h for Design
- Junior Developer Joe

  - 3 h for Development
  - 1 h for Testing
  - 1 h for Documentation

However we would like to say Bill has a total of 4.0 h a day and he can spend them on Dev, Testing, Doc, & Design as need be. Same for Joe, he has a total of 5 h a day and can spend them on Dev, Testing, & Doc.

Some sprints are very design and documentation heavy where some are mainly testing and deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. You can submit feature requests to Microsoft on [User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services).